# How to modify error message:Could not modify attributes on entry from DN in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, jboss-eap-7, jboss-tools, jboss-developer-studio, jboss-wildfly-11

I have setup a passwordpolicy on my openLDAP that is user is not able to change password, using his/her old password. Error message is working on my openLDAP but in keycloak the error message is different. See below image:

[image: Error Message]

I've searched that this message is located here: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/federation/ldap/src/main/java/org/keycloak/storage/ldap/idm/store/ldap/LDAPOperationManager.java

But i don't know where to find this java file in my keycloak-3.4.3.Final folder. And how to modify it.

I can't use the not recently used password policy: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.2/server_admin/topics/authentication/password-policies.html too since it is working only inside the keycloak db. And im using an LDAP federation.

Please help thank you.

Comment: What do the KC logs say?

Comment: There is No any logs on KC after i reset the password. @XtremeBiker

Comment: I found this post: http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2017-September/011711.html . It says KC only supports MSAD and translate the error message. Maybe that's why my error message is not translated because i am using openLDAP.